# Set Relative Layout To Fit ImageView

Tags: android

I have an xml file as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

            <!-- toolbar -->
            <include layout="@layout/snippet_top_sharetoolbar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_border_bottom">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout3img">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageShare"
                        android:src="@drawable/white_bg"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_for_image"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

         </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I need to fit layout relLayout3img to match exactly the imageview, not the other way around since I take a screenshot of that relative layout and download it.

I searched for any solutions but couldn't find any. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  It is unclear what you want.  Why isn't your solution above working?  What did you want it to do instead? Currently your relLayout3img should be the same size as your ImageView since you are using wrap_content for its size.

Comment: If you paste it in some xml file you'll see it's not wrapping the imageview even though it should have as you say. All I want is make the relative layout literally wrap the imageview

Comment: I need to take only the area inside the borders, but relative layout wraps it all. So the problem is caused because of the margins in the imageview. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: So the problem is you have an image that is 100px by 70px and you want the relative layout to be that size rather than 100dp by 100dp?

Comment: I actually solved the problem. I placed a dummy imageview in the area that my actual imageview puts margin and then wrapped my imageview with another layout. Now it seems working since I got rid of the margins